# error LNK2005 on an external dll

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 and trying to use a dynamic linked library that I have not wrote myself. I can define something Foo *foo; and everything is fine until I create a new object using Foo *foo = new Foo( params );
I get a whole list of errors:

```
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR110D.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>cyclone.lib(pworld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl std::_String_base::_Xran(void)" (?_Xran@_String_base@std@@SAXXZ) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > & __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::erase(unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?erase@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAEAAV12@II@Z)
1>cyclone.lib(pfgen.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl std::_String_base::_Xran(void)" (?_Xran@_String_base@std@@SAXXZ)
1>cyclone.lib(pworld.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl std::_String_base::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@_String_base@std@@SAXXZ) referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Grow(unsigned int,bool)" (?_Grow@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@IAE_NI_N@Z)
1>cyclone.lib(pfgen.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl std::_String_base::_Xlen(void)" (?_Xlen@_String_base@std@@SAXXZ)
1>C:\Users\deleo\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AdvancedPhysics - Copy\Debug\AdvancedPhysics.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So I cannot change any of the code of the dll itself.

I use a single #include (and I looked at the file, if is guarded with an #ifndef).
Anyone knows why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Comment: These are not linker errors you get from using a DLL, you get them from using a static library.  Which was built with grossly incompatible settings, not just for the runtime library (/MD vs /MT), also a different version of the C++ standard library.  Which has been changing a lot thanks to C++11.  You cannot use this library as-is, it needs to be rebuilt.  If you don't have source then contact the owner and ask for an update.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hans, I do have the original files. I think the original version was build using Visual Studio 2008 and I am using 2012. If I rebuild the .dlls using VS 2012, would that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your project and linked libraries must use the same VC++ version and the same compiler options. You can use PE (Portable Executable) viewer to view linker version to determine what compiler version that used to compile that DLL.

If your compiler version is same as DLL. Try to set `Runtime Library` in `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation` to `MT` or `MTd`.

Comment: I set the Runtime Library to MTd but I still get some errors (LNK2019 and LNK2001 this time) How do I check the compiler options?

Comment: There is no way to check compiler options. But it look like your DLL used difference version of VC++. Did you check the linker version? if not, ensure your DLL used the same VC++ version as your project.